# Get the name of the button that triggered the event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have an event handler that handles the click event of multiple buttons:

```
Private Sub primeHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _2s.Click, _3s.Click, _4s.Click, _5s.Click, _6s.Click

End Sub
```

_2s, _3s, etc are all buttons.
Now I need a way to determine which button triggered the event and also get the button's name **as string**. Any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: `sender` is the control which fired the event

Comment: What are you using it for? In my experience, this is almost always indicative of a design flaw elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

You can cast `sender` to type `Button` and access the Name property.

```
Private Sub primeHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _2s.Click, _3s.Click, _4s.Click, _5s.Click, _6s.Click
    Dim myButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim myName As String = myButton.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sender` - it's what it's designed to do.

```
MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Name);
```

If you're going to use it more than once, assign it to a variable to make it easier.

```
var button = (sender as Button);
MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
```