# How can i get the button that triggered the event in vb

Tags: vb.net

Trying to change the colour of the button that triggered the current event. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V7bw.png)

Copying this across multiple buttons however if i could get rid of the btnPos7.colour etc and change it to something like (trigger button).color then i can make one big function.

```
Private Sub btnPos7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPos7.Click
    currentButton = 7
    If started = True Then
        Call blockCheck()
        If blocked = False Then
            If (playerPos + 6) = 7 Or (playerPos - 6) = 7 Or (playerPos - 1) = 7 Then
                playerPos = 7
                btnPos7.BackColor = Color.Green
                For counter = 0 To 5
                    Call itemCheck()
                Next
            Else
                txtDisplay.Text += "You cannot move here"
            End If
        Else
            btnPos7.BackColor = Color.Black
            txtDisplay.Text += "The path is blocked. Find another way through"
        End If
    Else End If
    lblScore.Text = "Score: " & score
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the name of the button that triggered the event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059601/get-the-name-of-the-button-that-triggered-the-event)

Comment: Seen that and tried it but it doesn't work in this version of vb

Comment: @Md.KhairulHasan comes up with error on Ctype as keyword does not name a type

Comment: It works in EVERY version of VB.NET.  If what you did doesn't work then it's because you did it wrong.  Show us what you did so we can see what you did wrong.